# Monitoring the temperature of Nvidia RTX 30** VRAM?

Tags: nvidia, gpu, monitoring

Working with Ubuntu 20.04, is it possible to get any info about the **temperature of the VRAM** for a Nvidia graphic card (30** series)?

The command `nvidia-smi` does not give this specific datum. For example, on Windows I know that there exists the application HWinfo64, and the specific temperature I'm asking for, is referred as "junction temp". Anything similar on Ubuntu?

Many thanks

Answer (score -1):

I too have been trying to find out this vram junction memory temperature for Ubuntu but currently there is no way.

I've even messaged the dev for HwInfo on his forum and he said he has no plans to release this feature for Linux at this time. However I did hear there was something like this for HiveOS, but as far as Ubuntu nvidia-smi has no command at this time of writing February 2021.